# Method overloading with float and double type in super class and base class

Tags: java

Why float method is not considered of Derive class in below program?

In the below program when I assign derive object to base class at that time base.f(20) consider the Derive class int method but base.f(20.0f) is not considered Derive class float method.

Can you guys explain me what is the logic behind this?

```java
public class Tricky3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Derive derive = new Derive();
        System.out.println(derive.f(10));
        System.out.println(derive.f(10.0f));

        System.out.println("------------------New Logic-----------------");
        Base base = new Derive();
        System.out.println(base.f(20));
        System.out.println(base.f(20.0f));

    }
}

class Base {
    public int f(int i) {
        System.out.print("Base f (int): ");
        return i + 3;
    }
    public double f(double i) {
        System.out.print("Base f (double) : ");
        return i + 3.3;
    }
}

class Derive extends Base{
    public float f(float i) {
        System.out.print("Derive f (float) : ");
        return i + 3.3f;
    }
    public int f(int i) {
        System.out.print("Derive f (int): ");
        return i + 3;
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Derive f (int): 13

Derive f (float) : 13.3

------------------New Logic-----------------

Derive f (int): 23

Base f (double) : 23.3
```

Comment: Because the base class method takes a double as argument, whereas the derived class method doesn't: it takes a float. Those are not the same types, so the signatures of the methods are different, so one doesn't overrides the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `Base base` reference variable and `Derive derive` object.

`base.f(20.0f)` will try to find `Base.f(float)`method signature, when it cannot find `Base.f(float)` the **Dynamic Binding** with `Derive.f(float)` cannot happen, then it will search for closest method which can support `base.f(20.0f)` call which is `Base.f(double)`.

If you declare `f(float)` in `Base` class then Dynamic Binding will happen and `Derive.f(float)`
will be called.

Answer (score 2):

When you choose to declare a style

```
Parent p = new Child();
```

You are accessing members from parent and implementations from children execute runtime. Since your parent doesn't have method with float type it chosen from `Base`. If you override the same method in children, that executes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be reduced to the following snippet:

```java
class Base {
    public double f(double x) {
        System.out.println("Base.f");
        return x;
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    public float f(float x) {
        System.out.println("Derived.f");
        return x;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Derived().f(1.0f);           // Derived.f
        ( (Base)new Derived() ).f(1.0f); // Base.f
    }
}
```

When evaluating `new Derived().f(1.0f)` the compiler has the choice

- to implicitly convert the float parameter into a double and call `Base.f(double)`, or
- to call `Derived.f(float)` without conversion.

The compiler chooses the `Derived.f(float)` overload because it manages without conversion.

When evaluating `( (Base)new Derived() ).f(1.0f)` the compiler no longer knows about the `Derived.f(float)` overload and is forced to do the conversion and then call `Base.f(double)`.

The behavior would be different if `Derived.f` and `Base.f` had the same signature. Then the method would be overwritten and both statements would call `Derived.f`:

```java
class Base {
    public double f(double x) {
        System.out.println("Base.f");
        return x;
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    public double f(double x) {
        System.out.println("Derived.f");
        return x;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Derived().f(1.0f);           // Derived.f
        ( (Base)new Derived() ).f(1.0f); // Derived.f
    }
}
```